# Sitecore SXA - Scriban error with sc_beginfield, can't be found

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-sxa, scriban

I am getting this kinda issue with my scriban variants ˙`` error : The function `sc_beginfield` was not found ``.

Here is the template:

```
{{ sc_beginfield i_item 'Link' [['text', ' ']]}}
   {{ sc_link_text i_item 'Link' }}
<span class="fa fa-wrench icon-right" aria-hidden="true" data-ce-key="1202"></span>
{{ sc_endfield }}
```

Can somebody give me a hint what is wrong here. I think this code template is correct, but I sure can be wrong

Answer (score 0):

It seems sc_beingfield implementation is not there. Basically ensure you have below setting in website\App_Config\Modules\SXA\Foundation\Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Scriban.config

```
  <processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Scriban.Pipelines.GenerateScribanContext.AddFieldFunctions, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Scriban" resolve="true"/>
```

Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Scriban.dll

[image]